# How to update a data source via the API

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I'm using a mix of the powershell powerbi management library and the rest api to update a datasource. (as documented here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updatedatasourcesingroup#datasourceconnectiondetails)

`https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{0}/datasets/{1}/Default.UpdateDatasources` to update a data source. I'm passing in the workspace id for {0} and the dataset ID for {1}.

```
$datasets = Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $workspaceObj.Id
foreach($dataset in $datasets)
{
    $DatasetId = $dataset.Id.Guid

    $json = 
@'
{{
    "updateDetails": [{{
            "datasourceSelector": {{
                "datasourceType": "AnalysisServices",
                "connectionDetails": {{
                    "server": "{0}",
                    "database": "{1}"
                }}
            }},
            "connectionDetails": {{
                "server": "{0}",
                "database": "{1}"
            }}
        }}
    ]
}}
'@
    $json = [string]::Format($json, $AasServer, $modelName)
    $apiDatasetUrl = [string]::Format('https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{0}/datasets/{1}/Default.UpdateDatasources',$workspaceObj.Id , $DatasetId)
    Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers  -Method 'Post' -Body $json -Uri $apiDatasetUrl -ContentType 'application/json'
}
```

This results in a 404 error:

> Dataset {guid} is not found

What am I doing wrong? I cannot understand how the dataset cannot be found, when the guid comes from the Power BI api.

I've also tried including the "datasourceId" and the "gatewayId" in the json body, but this does not have an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was actually in my JSON, the first `connectionDetails` is the exact specification of the existing data source. The second `connectionDetails` contains the details to update. See below for correction (in capitals)

```
    $json = 
@'
{{
    "updateDetails": [{{
            "datasourceSelector": {{
                "datasourceType": "AnalysisServices",
                "connectionDetails": {{
                    "server": "MY-OLD-SERVER-NAME",
                    "database": "MY-OLD-MODEL-NAME"
                }},
      "datasourceId": "{2}",
      "gatewayId": "{3}"
            }},
            "connectionDetails": {{
                "server": "{0}",
                "database": "{1}"
            }}
        }}
    ]
}}
```

Comment: How did you get it to work. I followed your code after I tried my way. I am getting the same forbidden error 403 . I do a login-powerbi  I get the token fine and add it to the header. Is there any other headers I need to add if i followed your code. When i try this in postman it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [Dataset - Get Datasources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getdatasources):

```
$getUrl = [string]::Format('https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{0}/datasources',$DatasetId)
```

While (since you are getting datasets from some workspace `$datasets = Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $workspaceObj.Id`) you should use [Datasets - Get Datasources In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getdatasourcesingroup) and the endpoint URL should be like this:

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets/{datasetId}/datasources
```

i.e. you must also provide the group (workspace) ID.

Comment: Changing this still results in the same issue. Both endpoints return the same

Comment: I think this is a red herring, re-reading my script, $DataSsourceDetails is not referenced anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar project (PS cmdlets + rest) and faced similar issues as yours.

How are you connection to the API? Using a service principal, you are limited to the api calls you can make (which is poorly documented by MS).

The "404 not found" seems to me that you are not authorized to make a change to the dataset. You can try to login as a user using Login-PowerBI and see if you get a different response.

Your best options to debug are:
run the cmdlet [Resolve-PowerBIError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.profile/resolve-powerbierror?view=powerbi-ps) -Last to get more details of the error
Or use are tool like Fiddler to see the response of the API.